# Runtime error while handling large numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to write code for a problem that involves a function, that takes input numbers as Strings, and returns the remainder of that input when divided by 7 as an int.

Although the code works for smaller numbers, it prompts a runtime error when handling large numbers as input, shown as follows ..

```
Runtime error   time: 0.04 memory: 711168 signal:-1

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5‌​449495"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:470)
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:597)
    at Ideone.remainderWith7(Main.java:13)
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:22)
```

My code is as follows ..

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {
    int remainderWith7(String num) {
        // Your code here
        java.math.BigInteger bg = new java.math.BigInteger(num);
        //System.out.println(num);
        Integer n = bg.intValue();
        return (int) n % 7;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        // your code goes here
        Ideone id = new Ideone();
        System.out.println(id.remainderWith7("56495654565052555054535456545355495650575755555757575350505‌​44949525452505653565‌​54949515453545151525‌​15050575749545453535‌​54954555157565253514‌​94949495155515455545‌​65555575452555157505‌​55557495050564952514‌​95051505752545155495‌​65156515750555450545‌​35549535551525149535‌​25654525554535154515‌​05251575251494956515‌​35255515450515553515‌​15657545054505357535‌​55654575549575349565‌​351575054"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good on you for editing and specifying the error.  I only glanced and saw that you were using modulo after coercing the entire BigInteger down.  I've figured out part of the issue now.

Comment: (_I_ actually added the specific error after running it myself)

Comment: @qxz:  Okay, thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

How'd you paste that string in?  It looks like it contains a lot of [zero-width spaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) and [zero-width non-joiners](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm).

I say "looks like"; in actuality, you'd only ever be able to see those if you printed out the contents of the string's array, either with `Arrays.toString` and encapsulating that long string in a variable, or if you inspected it with a debugger.

Ultimately, that's what's leading you astray; Java is attempting to convert those Unicode characters to numbers, and since they're *not* numbers, they convert to -1.  This is why your code breaks, and this is also why it's not immediately apparent as to why it breaks.  There are more characters in that string than you're immediately led to believe.

The fix is to remove these characters from the string.

```
String num = ""; // enter your long number here; not repeating it for brevity's sake
num = num.replace("\u200C", "").replace("\u200B", "");
```

Now you can get back to other issues with the code, such as not using `BigInteger.mod` when you want to do a modulo (because *trust me*, using `%` ain't gonna give you the right answer with an integer as large as that).